# Grails: TypeMismatchException - Provided id of the wrong type - Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have the following domain model class:

```
class UserSettings
{
  static mapping = {
    id name: 'pid', generator: 'assigned'
  }

  Integer pid
}
```

And I'm trying to get an instance of the user settings like this:

```
UserSettings.get(new Integer("12345"))
```

However, I get the following error

```
Provided id of the wrong type for class UserSettings. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long
```

I've also tried passing it a basic int type, and I get the same error.  It's like somewhere along the way the "get" method casts my Integer into a Long.  Changing the type of the "pid" property in the UserSettings domain class to Long fixes things, however, since I'm integrating with a legacy database, I need the ID to be an Integer not a Long.

Comment: What if you call it `id` instead of `pid`?  You can change the column name independently of the property name in the mappings block so you can still match the legacy DB schema.

Comment: Changing it to id actually fixes the problem ... however, now I'd like to know why.  Isn't the whole point of setting the name of the id in the mapping closure so that you can use a different property name for the id?

Comment: I know that if you use a _composite_ key of more than one property then you have to pass a prototype object to `get` rather than passing the property values directly ([ref](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys)).  I haven't managed to trace through the code to confirm this but maybe the same applies to any case where the identifier is not the property named `id`.

Answer (score 2):

In general don't use `new Integer`, `new Long`, `new Boolean`, etc. Use literals and let Java autobox the values for you. If you look at the source of the `Integer` and `Long` you'll see that their `valueOf` methods (which are used when autoboxing) keep a cache of 256 of the smaller values. This won't result in a significant savings but is a good idea, and since you get the same thing with the constructor and `valueOf`, it's best to always use `valueOf`.

Further, GORM will convert the input id to the correct type for the domain class. This is why `SomeDomainClass.get(params.id)` works in controllers - even though all params are strings, GORM can easily convert from a string to a numeric type.

So your best bet here is to work less:

```
UserSettings.get("12345")
```

Comment: Your example still produces the exact same error message.  The String gets converted to an Integer which then somehow gets converted to a Long and produces the problem.